# Can I create a email from a mailto: link which is prepopulated with an image?

Tags: html, email, outlook

so I have a link like this:

```
mailto:someone@nowhere.com?subject=Hello%20You&body=Some%20Body%20Text
```

and I'd like it to open an email which has an image (ideally) embedded in the mail, or attached to the mail.  Ideally I'd also like to add a Table from Excel to the mail as well.

```
mailto:someone@nowhere.com?subject=Hello%20You&body=Some%20Body%20Text%0A<a%20href="image.jpg"/>
```

Is this possible or am I living in dream land?

Comment: no language, just a plain html link on a web page

Comment: HTML is a language. Add it to the tags so that the respective users can answer.

Comment: According to [RFC 2368](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2368), the mailto URL scheme, it is possible to set a body parameter. So, I guess your attempt (second link) should work if properly encoded. Have you tested that?

Comment: Try escaping not only the spaces. Especialy `/`, '"' and maybe `>`, `<`

Comment: when I've tested it I just get a plain text link in the email, outlook doesn't actually insert the image (not tested in other email programs but this is sort of internal so we can assume outlook is the client)

Comment: @SamHolder then you should figure out how to embed images in e-mail. To begin with, you probably need the `img` tag instead of `a`. I don't know much about html in e-mail so I can't help you much further.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester thanks, changing the tag and escaping everything doesn't seem to matter I still get a plain text version of the link rather than an 'html' email regardless of the settings in outlook

Comment: @SamHolder does it result in an actual clickable link or do you mean you literally get `<a href=...` in your mail? In case of the latter, this is because the MIME header has not been set properly. Also, try to add at least an `html` and `body` tag to put the `img` in.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester no clickable link, just plain text.  I'll try with the html tags as well.  The mime type should be set ok (as I can add pictures to the opened email by pasting them in)

Comment: @SamHolder that's not a sign that your mailto link sets the correct headers, because the editor might as well change all of that stuff the moment you paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

No.

**Long Answer**

It is not possible to send a Image (as HTML), according to the specification RFC2368

> The special hname "body" indicates that the associated hvalue is the body of the message. The "body" hname should contain the content for the first text/plain body part of the message. The mailto URL is primarily intended for generation of short text messages that are actually the content of automatic processing (such as "subscribe" messages for mailing lists), not general MIME bodies.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt

**So what i should do?**

Your best bet would be, to have a server side formular.

```
<form action="/pathto/serverside/mailer" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" />
    <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Your email-adress" />
    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Your message" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

**PHP Way**

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host     = $host;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $username;  
$mail->Password = $password; 
$mail->From     = $from;
$mail->FromName = $fromName;
$mail->AddAddress($to , $toName);
$mail->Subject  = $subject;
$mail->Body     = $body; //Your Html
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

This is based on the PHPMailer Library https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer, because the built in `mail()` function is the devil in person ;)

**ASP Way**

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, message);
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
client.Send(mail);
```